# htaccess 301 Redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, slug

I have the following URL structures for my website:

```
http://domain.com/slug/1/test-test.html
http://domain.com/slug/2/test-test.html
```

and i want to change it to

```
http://domain.com/new-1-test-test.html
http://domain.com/new-2-test-test.html
```

i have already tried

```
RewriteRule ^slug$ /new- [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?my\slug /new [R=301,L]
```

but it does't work..
anyone know how to redirect this with htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^slug/([0-9])/(.*)$ /new-$1-$2 [R-301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - `RewriteRule ^slug/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /new-$1-$2 [R=301, L]`